# Logstash - convert microseconds to milliseconds

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am using Logstash to ingest some redis slow logs that report in microseconds.  I'd like to convert this to milliseconds but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the config:

```
ruby {
    code => "event.set('redis.slowlog.duration.ms', event.get('redis.slowlog.duration.us').to_f / 1000)"
}
```

But the results end up as zero:

[image: Index Results]

Any suggestions?

Comment: The ruby syntax looks fine.  Are you doing anything to create redis.slowlog.duration.us in your config that maybe hasn't run before you hit this ruby block?  You might also add an exception handler to your ruby block.

Comment: The value is added by a filebeat redis module.  I'm assuming everything is coming in at the same time.

Here's the filebeat:

filebeat.modules:
- module: redis

filebeat.prospectors:
- type: redis
  hosts: ["localhost:6379"]
  fields:
    data_type: redis-slowlog

tags: ["redis-slowlog"]

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["10.0.0.76:5045"]

Comment: Sounds fine - it was just something to check.  Try the exception handler and see if you get any more info.

Comment: I added the exception handler but it doesn't seem to be triggering an exception.